# Advice on BDD for iOS needed

Tags: ios, unit-testing, bdd, xctest, ocmock

Inspired by [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-15/behavior-driven-development.html) issue on [objc.io](http://www.objc.io) I decided to try out BDD on my new project. Here is my problem: I want to test that `MYCredentialStorage` somehow persists credentials I ask it to store, namely that next time app is launched I would get the very same credential. `MYCredentialStorage` uses keychain, so I could mock it and verify that `SecItemAdd` or `SecItemUpdate` functions are called, but I am not supposed to test (or know of) `MYCredentialStorage`’s private methods, right?
I’m sure I’m not the only one faced this problem, so I’m asking for your advice since I’m very new to BDD.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at another article from the same objc.io issue - dependency injection: http://www.objc.io/issue-15/dependency-injection.html. Basically you can inject a mock of keychain into `MYCredentialStorage` (but maybe you'll need to create a wrapper for `SecItem`* methods).

Comment: I agree with @MichałCiuba - there's no generic way to express that an item will persist between executions of your app. If you're going the DI route, I'd do what he says. If you aren't doing DI, I wouldn't be shy about mocking the keychain storage or your private methods. I'd be explicit in the naming of the test to express exactly what the expectations are.

Comment: Thank you, if I could I would accept both of your comments as an answer. I ended up using a constructor injection and mocking keychain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the comments**

*Michał Ciuba wrote:*

Take a look at another article from the same objc.io issue - dependency injection: objc.io/issue-15/dependency-injection.html. Basically you can inject a mock of keychain into MYCredentialStorage (but maybe you'll need to create a wrapper for SecItem* methods).

*Ben Flynn wrote:*

I agree with @MichałCiuba - there's no generic way to express that an item will persist between executions of your app. If you're going the DI route, I'd do what he says. If you aren't doing DI, I wouldn't be shy about mocking the keychain storage or your private methods. I'd be explicit in the naming of the test to express exactly what the expectations are.